# Android AWS Lambda CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

Tags: android, aws-lambda

I'm new to android studio and following this guide [AWS Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-android-example.html).  I made some changes as I don't want to copy and paste the exact code from the guide.  As stated I'm getting this error when clicking the app button from my android studio:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo, PID: 14152
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:162)
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:371)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:566)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:678)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:465)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:485)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:406)
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:364)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy1.echo(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.youruserpools.AboutApp$2.onClick(AboutApp.java:80)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14152 SIG: 9
```

Here is my source code:

```
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutBack);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(), "pool-id", Regions.US_EAST_1);

            Log.v("TAG", "ABC " + getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().toString() + " : " + cognitoProvider.getIdentityProvider());

            LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    Regions.US_EAST_1, cognitoProvider);

            final MyInterface myInterface = factory.build(MyInterface.class);
            Log.v("TAG", "HERE 0 " + factory.getClientContext().toString());
            NameInfo nameInfo = new NameInfo("John", "Doe");
            Log.v("TAG", "HERE 1 " + nameInfo.getFirstName() + " : " + nameInfo.getLastName());
                myInterface.echo(nameInfo);


        }
    });
```

MyInterface

```
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaFunction;

public interface MyInterface {
    @LambdaFunction
    String echo(NameInfo nameInfo);

    @LambdaFunction(functionName = "echo")
    void noEcho(NameInfo nameInfo);
}
```

Any help idea on what am I missing?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` means, literally, you did network call on the main  thread. `myInterface.echo(nameInfo)` is a network call, you should put in in a new `Thread` or `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask`.